# PostgreSQL function - Invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: postgresql, function, syntax, casting

I trying to execute a PostgreSQL function, but it is getting error.

This function already exists in DataBase:

```
DECLARE


  vCur REFCURSOR;
  vSql varchar(2000);
  vStr varchar(10);
  vAux varchar(4000);
  vRet bigint;

BEGIN
  vRet := '';
  -- monta o SELECT dinâmico
  vSql := '';
    vSql := vSql || 'select SUM(F_PRD_SALDO_PRODUTO(A.CD_EMPRESA, '''|| PI_CD_SALDO ||''', A.CD_PRODUTO, ''' || PI_DT_SALDO::varchar || ''')) ';
    vSql := vSql || 'from VR_PRD_PRODEMP A ';
    vStr := 'where ';
  -- Filtro de empresa
  if (PI_CD_EMPRESA IS NOT NULL) then
    vSql := vSql || vStr || 'A.CD_EMPRESA IN ( ' || PI_CD_EMPRESA || ' ) ';
    vStr := 'and ';
  end if;
  -- Filtro de produto
  if (PI_CD_PRODUTO <> 0) then
    vSql := vSql || vStr || 'A.CD_PRODUTO = ''' || PI_CD_PRODUTO::varchar || ''' ';
    vStr := 'and ';
  end if;
  -- Passo 2: abre e executa o cursor dinâmico usando a cursor variable
  open vCur for EXECUTE vSql;
  loop
    fetch vCur into vAux;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND; /* apply on vCur */
    vRet := vAux;
  end loop;
  close vCur;
  vRet := coalesce(vRet, '0');
  return (vRet)::numeric;
end;
```

I'm trying to execute this command:

`SELECT public.f_dic_sld_prd_produto('301','1',14708,'2019-01-01 00:00:00')`

But It get follow error:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
> SQL state: 22P02
> Context: PL/pgSQL function f_dic_sld_prd_produto(text,text,bigint,timestamp without time zone) line 12 at assignment

*Note: This function is default in the system that is used by our company. In other installation that uses Oracle, this error does not occur.*

Please, could someone help to solve it?!

Comment: It's hard to tell where's the issue coz we don't have your tables or data which is specifically causing the error. Debug each line and try to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: You should never use this function, as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.